# Are there naming conventions in yaml format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

Are there naming conventions I can follow when writing an i18n yaml file for my Rails app?

I have a "Save changes" button that corresponds to `Users.update`. I'm not sure what to call the key:

```
users.edit.update
users.edit.update_button
users.edit.save_changes
users.edit.btn_update
```

Are there any naming conventions I can follow?

Comment: See example http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml Using `User.update` as key also possible (and `users.edit.update` too).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the canonical YAML naming style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771226/what-is-the-canonical-yaml-naming-style)

Answer (score 3):

There is no set convention. You should choose the most natural approach for your application and your programming language.